# Поиск DOM элементов сверху

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть таблица:

```
 <tr id="entry">
     <td>
    </td> 
    <td rel="upon"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="entry">
     <td rel="upon"></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
//В общем, около 10 таких
```

Подскажите, как проверить через jquery, есть ли вверху `<tr>`, и если есть нужно через opacity 0.1 скрыть "rel". 
Пробовал наподобие такого:

```
if($(this).closest('tr').attr("rel").next()) {
...
```

Что-то не получается

Comment: Про opacity 0.1 не понял

Comment: Проверить для конкретно td или для всех?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
$('.entry td[rel=upon]').css({ opacity: 0.1 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="entry">
    <td>
      Я буду виден
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="entry">
    <td rel=upon>
      Я невидимка(нет)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Да, вот так спасибо. Только eq(0) еще добавил

Answer (score 0):

у первой строки изменить прозрачность:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr').eq(0).css({'opacity': 0.1});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class ="entry">
    <td>1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class ="entry">
    <td>2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S. Избегайте на странице одинаковых id, замените на class.
P.S.S. Так же можно обратить внимание на [closest()](https://jquery-docs.ru/closest/), [prev()](https://jquery-docs.ru/prev/)

Comment: Не, он спросил как изменить прозрачность  любого элемента с атрибутом  `rel`  при условии что он размещен внутри `<td>`.

Comment: @Uranus, когда ответ был дан. В вопросе еще не было ничего про rel внутри td)